How to clip fixed width child by parent with no fixed width in SwiftUI
Problem statement:
I have a child (HStack) inside a parent (Vstack). The HStack contains an unknown number of items with a fixed width, so its total width is also unknown.
I want to cut off the content of the HStack at the trailing edge, given by its "maximal allowed" width (the width that the HStack would expand to if it had for example a Color inside - see example).
Due to the Parent not having a fixed width though, the VStack gets stretched to the full width of the children, which can be wider than the screen.
Example:

Code to reproduce:
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUITestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Goal (visual):")
            HStack {
                ForEach(0...5, id: \.self) { number in
                    Color(.blue)
                        .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .clipped()
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: 370, alignment: .leading) // <- without setting this fixed width...
            .clipped()
            .background(.red)
            .padding(.vertical, 4)
            Text("Problem:")
            HStack {
                ForEach(0...10, id: \.self) { number in
                    Color(.blue)
                        .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .clipped()
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            .background(.red)
            .padding(.vertical, 4)
        }
        .padding(8)
        .background(.green)
        VStack {
            Text("Size of HStack and VStack should be:")
            HStack {
                Color(.red).frame(height: 60)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            .background(.red)
            .padding(.vertical, 4)
        }
        .padding(8)
        .background(.green)
    }
}

#Preview {
    SwiftUITestView()
}


I have found a workaround using a disabled horizontal ScrollView, but I would love to see how this can be done "the right" way.

ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(0...10, id: \.self) { number in
                        Color(.blue)
                            .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                            .clipped()
                    }
                }
            }.disabled(true)


I would say, your workaround with the ScrollView is actually quite acceptable.
Another way to do it is to reserve the space necessary for showing the items, then show them in an overlay and apply clipping to the overlay.

If you know the maximum height of the items, you could use Color.clear with a fixed height to reserve the space. Otherwise, the tallest single item can be used as a placeholder and shown as hidden.

For the case of when there are only a small number of items that don't fill the full width, you can determine the alignment by applying a frame with maxWidth: .infinity to the HStack in the overlay. By default, the alignment is .center, but you can add an alignment parameter if you want it to be different.


private var fixedSizeItem: some View {
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
        .fill(.blue)
        .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
}

VStack {
    Text("Example:")
    fixedSizeItem
        .hidden()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .overlay(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack {
                ForEach(0...10, id: \.self) { number in
                    fixedSizeItem
                }
            }
            .background(.red)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity) // To center when only a few items
        }
        .clipped()
        .padding(.vertical, 4)
}
.padding(8)
.background(.green)


Instead of using an overlay, two other approaches would be:

Wrap the HStack with a GeometryReader, to measure the available width. Then set this width on the HStack (with alignment .leading) and clip. However, a GeometryReader will grab all the space it can, including vertical space. If you know the maximum height of the items then you can apply this height to the GeometryReader, but otherwise it may consume too much vertical space.

A custom Layout would be another way to do it. Good luck if you go for this approach!



You already found a view that expands naturally - Color, so just add the HStack as an overlay of that, and put clipped() on the Color.
Color.clear.frame(height: 60)
    .overlay(alignment: .leading) {
        HStack {
            ForEach(0...10, id: \.self) { number in
                Color(.blue)
                    .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
            }
        }
        .background(.red)
        .padding(.vertical, 4)
    }
    .clipped()


That said, I would also like to point out that using a ScrollView is not a bad solution either, if you use a LazyHStack.
ScrollView(.horizontal) {
    LazyHStack {
        ForEach(0...10, id: \.self) { number in
            Color(.blue)
                .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .clipped()
        }
    }
    .frame(height: 60)
    .background(.red)
    .padding(.vertical, 4)
}
.scrollDisabled(true)

ScrollView and LazyHStack work together and will prevent the clipped views from being drawn at all. This will help performance if there are a lot of items in the LazyHStack.

Wouldn't you get the same performance gain if a LazyHStack is used in the overlay version, without using a ScrollView? I would expect the LazyHStack to render only what is actually shown, so views that are outside the clipped region are not even created.

@BenzyNeez I don't think so. I remember seeing a question saying that lazy stacks are only lazy in ScrollViews (and was asking how to work around it).

@BenzyNeez Not exactly the question I saw, but this talks about the same point.

The difference in this case is that the width is constrained (by the size of the overlay) and the content is clipped.

@BenzyNeez I just tested by putting 0..<100 in the ForEach and .onAppear { print(number) } on each item. onAppear gets called for all 100 items.

Yes, I did a similar test and got the same result! So that's clarified then :)
